# How to do unit testing in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Anyone knows how to do unit testing in a WP 8.1 RT app? There is almost no resources in the internet about this or even WinRT.

Comment: It's just yet another library, what is so inherently different from "normal" unit testing?

Comment: I've never done it. So, there's no starting point with RT. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jeroen: You're wrong. It's not just another library. There's a full unit test environment for WP that's shipped with VS.

Comment: @Fred: I am aware there is a specific project template for it. But there is nothing different about unit tests in that template compared to unit tests in another template. They all have the same annotations and workings, the only difference is that the WP Unit Test template will create an app environment and run your tests on it. But you don't have to do anything differently, it's just unit-testing as usual.

Comment: But hat's the essential point. I think (and I might be wrong) that most people are confused with the thought of having their test methods for WP a) wrapped inside a proper separate project b) deployed on the emulator and c) tested with output. It's a little different from "normal" tests that you run on a system/server/VM that's entirely controlled by you.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new project inside your solution. Choose a **Unit Test App** template (see screenshot).
2. Create a test class with a test method inside that project. This could look like this:

   ```
   [TestClass]
   public class FooTestUnit
   {
       [TestMethod]
       public void TestFooBarProperty () {
           int referenceValue = 42;
           int actualValue = methodToTest();
           Assert.AreEqual(referenceValue, actualValue);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. From the main menu choose: **Tests / Run all tests**.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so how to test a View of the main project with this?